# Renaming field in Mongoid does not update field in class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongoid

When I rename a field in Mongoid, it successfully updates the field in MongoDB, but it does not update the field in the ruby code:

```
class Example
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :apple, type: String, as: :c_apple
end

Example.all
 => #<Mongoid::Criteria
  selector: {}
  options:  {}
  class:    Example
  embedded: false>

Example.all.rename("apple" => "d_apple")
  MOPED: 127.0.0.1:27017 UPDATE       database=core collection=examples selector={} update={"$rename"=>{"apple"=>"d_apple"}} flags=[:multi]
                         COMMAND      database=core command={:getlasterror=>1, :w=>1} runtime: 1.2460ms
 => {"connectionId"=>2, "updatedExisting"=>false, "n"=>0, "syncMillis"=>0, "writtenTo"=>nil, "err"=>nil, "ok"=>1.0} 

e = Example.new
 => #<Example _id: 5bfdbf103ed1492f9a000001, apple(c_apple): nil> 

 e.d_apple
NoMethodError: undefined method `d_apple' for #<Example _id: 5bfdbf103ed1492f9a000001, apple(c_apple): nil>
```

Why are the changes in MongoDB not reflected in class definition?

Comment: "but it does not update the field in the ruby code" - indeed, this is simply not what this method is supposed to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you run `#rename`, you interact with MongoDB. The change of document structure is stored in the database. This method does not interact with ruby source code, you need to edit it by yourself.

Btw. I can't recall any ruby/rails method (besides ones in rake tasks and generators) that interacts with the source code stored in files.

Comment: I need to use class_eval then to open up the class and modify the code and then reload the documents dynamically

Comment: Why do you want to do it dynamically? You can rename it in the source code and then reload the app.

Btw in production settings it's safer to copy field content instead of renaming it.

Comment: I need to do it dynamically because field name is based on user input.

Comment: So you want to rename field in the database basing on user input? Quite risky, I assume you're doing a tool for mongo management.

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I want to do

Comment: @Donato: if you're making a db management tool, then mongoid is of no use to you. Precisely because you don't know the schema beforehand and (I assume) do not care at all about relations. Your best course of action (IMHO) is to use the "raw" mongo driver.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev But I use Mongoid for a lot of other things, Rails-style querying methods, validations, associations, and a ton of other useful features. Why must I redo all this tested work just because one small feature involves the ability to add and delete fields dynamically. That's it. Everything else Mongoid is used for.

Comment: @Donato I see. Just redo the dynamic part then.